# what are the best ways to create the json object in BigQuery by joining multiple tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

****lets assume we have tables like company,employee and employee_address tables.Here company can have multiple employees and employee may have multiple address.Please help with the query to generate the below json.**
Sql for table creation:

```
create table company
(
company_id string,
comapnay_name string
);
insert into  company values("C1","TCSE");
create table employee
(
company_id string,
employee_id string,
employee_type string
);
insert into employee values("C1","RP1","Principal"),
("C1","RP11","CEO");
create table employee_address
(
company_id string,
employee_id string,
employee_address_id string,
adrees_detail_text string
);
insert into employee_address values
("C1","RP1","RP1A1","kadapa"),
("C1","RP1","RP1A2","B mattam"),
("C1","RP11","RP11A1","kadapa")**
```

**Below is the expected json output, please provide the best bigquery query **

```
[
    {"company_id":"C1",
    "comapnay_name":"TCSE",
    "empdetails":[
    {
    "employee_id":"RP11",
    "employee_type":"CEO",
    "employeeaddress":[
    {
        "company_id":"C1",
        "employee_id":"RP11",
        "employee_address_id":"RP11A1",
        "adrees_detail_text":"kadapa"
    }
    ]
        },
        
    {
        "employee_id":"RP1",
        "employee_type":"Principal",
        "employeeaddress":[
        {
        "company_id":"C1",
        "employee_id":"RP1",
        "employee_address_id":"RP1A1",
        "adrees_detail_text":"kadapa"
        },
        {"company_id":"C1",
        "employee_id":"RP1",
        "employee_address_id":"RP1A2",
        "adrees_detail_text":"B mattam"
        }
        ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

**I tried the below query ,but its not working as expected.**

```
with emp_add_array as
(select company_id,employee_id,array_agg(to_json_string(emp_addr)) as cemp_addr_array 
from employee_address  as emp_addr group by  company_id,employee_id ),
emp_emp_addr as
(select emp.company_id,emp.employee_id,emp.employee_type,cemp_addr_array as employeeaddress
from  employee emp left outer join  emp_add_array on 
emp.employee_id=emp_add_array.employee_id
 ),
 cmp_emp_addr_all as
 ( select company_id,array_agg(to_json_string(empaddrall)) as empaddrdetails from emp_emp_addr as empaddrall group by company_id),
cmpall as
(
select cmp.company_id,comapnay_name,empaddrdetails
from company as cmp left outer join cmp_emp_addr_all on cmp.company_id=cmp_emp_addr_all.company_id
)  select company_id,array_agg(to_json_string(t)) as employee  from cmpall as t group by company_id
```

Comment: Its really hard to understand from the **JSON**  response you have posted since it is an invalid one. Can you **edit** your post and `add some sample data` for each of your  tables and try to post a `valid JSON format response` from that data ? In the mean time you can also check [TO_JSON_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string) method which converts rows into `JSON`.You will be needing this method to get the desired output.

Comment: please find the updated details.i tried the below query but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query produced the expected json.

```
with emp_add_array as
(select company_id,employee_id,array_agg(TO_JSON(emp_addr)) as cemp_addr_array 
from employee_address  as emp_addr group by  company_id,employee_id ),
emp_emp_addr as
(select emp.company_id,emp.employee_id,emp.employee_type,cemp_addr_array as employeeaddress
from  employee emp left outer join  emp_add_array on 
emp.employee_id=emp_add_array.employee_id
 ),
 cmp_emp_addr_all as
 ( select company_id,array_agg(to_json(empaddrall)) as empdetails from emp_emp_addr as empaddrall group by company_id),
cmpall as
(
select cmp.company_id,comapnay_name,empdetails
from company as cmp left outer join cmp_emp_addr_all on cmp.company_id=cmp_emp_addr_all.company_id
) , cmpall_json as
(select array_agg(to_json(t)) as company  from cmpall as t group by company_id)
select to_json(t1) as companydetails from cmpall_json as t1
```